# Как проверять значение из столбца на дубликат с JS в Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, datatable, google-forms

На данный момент, в **Google Apps Script** реализовал код для автоматической отправки письма после заполнения формы.
Сейчас очень важно в коде, там где есть комментарий "ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ОЧЕНЬ НУЖНА ПРОВЕРКА НА ДУБЛИКАТ!", вписать условие, которое будет проверять есть ли уже почта, которую ввел человек или нет, и если есть дубликат - отправить одно письмо, а если нет - другое(которое сейчас в коде есть)

Вот и вопрос: как этот код реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

```
  function sendEmailToClient() {
  
  //Текущая Гугл Таблица записана в переменную:
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //Лист текущей таблицы с именем "Таблица", в который загружаются ответы из формы, записан в переменную:
  var listAnswers = ss.getSheetByName('Таблица'); 
  
  //Получен email клиента из ячейки с адресом: последняя строка, 6 ряд, - и записан в переменную:
  var clientEmail = listAnswers.getRange(listAnswers.getLastRow(),6).getValue();
//ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ОЧЕНЬ НУЖНА ПРОВЕРКА НА ДУБЛИКАТ!
  
  //Тело письма, отформатированное в html-разметке, записано в переменную:
  var body = 
      'Письмо';
  //В описании кода приведены дополнительные пояснения относительно html-разметки
  
  //Отправлено письмо клиенту (отправителем будет тот, кто запускает скрипт):
  //Для отправки используется функция sendEmail (по-правильному: метод класса MailApp)
  
MailApp.sendEmail(clientEmail, "Письмо",'',{htmlBody: body});
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var clientEmails = listAnswers
  .getRange(2,6,listAnswers.getLastRow()-2)
  .getValues().flat();
if(clientEmails.includes(clientEmail)) {
  // адрес уже есть, отправляем письмо для дубликатов
} else {
  // адрес новый, отправляем письмо для новичков
};
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Но я вставлю код и вообще не понимаю, что нужно сделать дальше. Эта проверка необходима для того, чтобы отправить один тип письма - пытался дальше вставлять "var body" и текст, но код перестал работать, триггер не срабатывал

Comment: @Ilya, попробуйте добавить проверку в вилку условия. Конечно, реализация не самая надежна, но если ответы шлют нечасто, то подойдет.

Comment: @contributorpw большое спасибо! Все работает!! 
Да, заявки будут падать нечасто, без перегруза, так что этот вариант 100% подходит

Comment: @Ilya, если ответ подошел, то отметьте его как решение, спасибо.